# Node modules usage error

Tags: node.js, module, amd, node-modules

Ive node moudle which i need to **export** two functions and **get** to both of the function a parameter arg1,I try with the following I got error,what am I doing wrong here ?

UPDATE

Ive two method inside module

```
1. I need to expose it outside and to call it explicit from other
 module with parameter
```

like

```
require('./controller/module')(functionName1)(parameter);
```

2. another function(functionName2) in this module which I need to call it explicit with two parameter ,how should I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to do, but i think you want something like that:

```
module.exports = function (arg1)  {
  return {
    server: function (params1) {
      //do something with arg1 and params1
    },
    proc: function (params2) {
     //do something with arg1 and params2
   }
 }
};
```

And using the module:

```
var arg1 = 'whatever'
var myMod = require('myMod')(arg1);
myMod.server();
myMod.proc();
```

**Option 2**

If i look at your new example

```
require('./controller/module')(functionName1)(parameter);
```

you need module that exports a function that returns another function ([Higher Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)).

So for example:

```
module.exports = function(functionName1) {
    if(functionName1 === 'server'){
        return function server(parameter){
          //do your stuff here
       }
    }

    if(functionName1 === 'proc'){
        return function proc(parameter){
          //do your stuff here
       }
    }    
};
```

Comment: Thanks I need something a bit diffrent , I update the question ,is it more clear now ?